# Citing a Book in Projects/ Research Papers?

Tags: research-process, citations, journals, research-undergraduate, books

I am Currently Working on Writing my *Undergraduate Minor Project Report*. For that I need to *Study Various Topics* from *Various Books*.

Now, My Process is to Read the Chapters Thoroughly and then write them in my own words (Basically *Paraphrasing*). But this isn't like Paraphrasing a Paragraph or a Statement. It's a **Whole Chapter**.

**So, Should I Cite the Book from which I read the Chapter ?**

If Yes, Then **How ?**, Because the Topics would be Spread over a Range of Pages.

Now, I know about Research Papers that this will be Considered as Basic Knowledge and Would'nt be cited. **Am I Right ?**

Comment: _My Process is to Read the Chapters Thoroughly and then write them in my own words (Basically Paraphrasing). But this isn't like Paraphrasing a Paragraph or a Statement. It's a Whole Chapter._ How are you avoiding plagiarism?

Comment: I was Thinking that, Since this Knowledge is the Basis for the Presented work, And Has been taken from a Book Instead of Some Else's Direct Work. It's not Necessary to cite it.

Comment: You're wrong: Taking something from any source (the original or some later publication on it) and passing it off as your own is plagiarism. (Some exceptions exist, e.g., you needn't cite Georg Ohm. That said, if you were to read a textbook on Ohm's law and paraphrase the content without citation, that would be plagiarism.)

Answer (score 1):

> Should I Cite the Book from which I read the Chapter ?

Yes, doing otherwise is surely plagiarism.

> If Yes, Then How ?, Because the Topics would be Spread over a Range of Pages.

You could open with: The following paraphrases A, B & C [1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/157615/citing-a-book-in-projects-research-papers/157632#comment420650_157615).

> I know about Research Papers that this will be Considered as Basic Knowledge and Would'nt be cited.

The phrase *Basic knowledge* is subjective. Regardless, over-citing is harmless.

Comment: I'm going to write these Topics in the Theoretical Framework Section of my Dissertation. Instead of Just writing the Definitions, How should I Explain these Topics without Paraphrasing ??

Comment: Since, I have studied these Topics from the Book Itself.

Comment: I'm Really Desperate Right Now, The Deadlines are Closing In and I have a Lot to do, And I'm Really New at this Process.